# Calling a QTip in JS for every item in foreach issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, qtip

I have this in my view:

```
  <%--
  The training module list
  --%>
  <div id="training-mod-list-<%: categoryName.Replace(' ', '-') %>" class="training-module-list">
  <% foreach (var module in categoryGroup)
  { %>
    <div class="training-module-row">                                 
      <div class="training-module-name-<%: module.TrainingModuleId %>">    
          <script type="text/javascript">
             <%: Html.GetQTip(module.TrainingModuleId, "", "", QTipPosition.Right,true,""); %> //get error here it has some invalid arguments?
          </script> 
         <%: module.TrainingModuleName %>
      </div>
    </div>
 <% } %>
```

when I hover over each training module name i want a QTip to show.

Then GetQtip:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString GetQTip(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string propertyName, string message, string propertyNameOverride = "", QTipPosition position = QTipPosition.Right, bool includeEvents = true, string title = "")
 {
  string qtipPosition = String.Empty;

  switch (position)
  {
    case QTipPosition.Right:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'left center', at: 'right center'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Left:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'right center', at: 'left center'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Top:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'top middle', at: 'bottom middle'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Bottom:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'bottom middle', at: 'top middle'";
      break;
  }

  if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyNameOverride))
    propertyName = propertyNameOverride;

  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
    title = htmlHelper.Resource(Resources.Global.Title.Information);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append(String.Concat("$('#", propertyName, "').removeData('qtip').qtip({content: {text:"));
  sb.Append(String.Concat("'", message, "', title: { text: '", title, "', button: false }}, position: { ", qtipPosition, " }"));
  if (includeEvents)
    sb.Append(", show: { event: 'focus mouseenter', solo: true, ready: false }, hide: 'blur'");
    sb.Append(", style: { classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-yellow' } });");

    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
  }
}
```

for now the message parameter can just be a any string
Can some one explain to me how to its going to work to show a qtip for every training module id? the message parameter will later contain points specific to each training module id made up in an html string

thanks

Comment: New questions: did you mean to leave out a ":" for your `<%`? Shouldn't it be `<%: Html.GetQTip`? Maybe it was a typo or maybe it's unnecessary. Also, why are you using the syntax `position: QTipPosition.Right`? Why include the "position: "?

Comment: I edited my OP again :) I now have something wrong with the parameter list

Comment: Is `module.TrainingModuleId` an int or string? It might matter more because you're passing it to a function that expects certain types. Also, I wonder if `QTipPosition.Right` is available/valid in this context. I wouldn't know. Try replacing the function declaration as allowing a string, and then actually pass a string - just to see if that's the problem

Comment: <%: Html.GetQTip(module.TrainingModuleId.ToString(), module.TrainingModuleName,"",QTipPosition.Right,true,"") %> this line works now, the problem was the type of the first parameter, thanks VERY much :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `TrainingModuleId` parameter from an `int` to a `String` for the HTML helper.

```
<%: Html.GetQTip(module.TrainingModuleId.ToString(), "", "", QTipPosition.Right,true,""); %>
```